# Run git gc on multiple repositories

Tags: git, bash

I have a git repository root at `/git`

There are different depth of paths, such as:

```
/git/project/project1/module1.git
/git/project/project1/module2.git
/git/project/project2/dev/module1.git
/git/library/libgit2.git
/git/library/jquery/jquery.git
```

How to I run `git gc` recursively in all repos inside `/git`?

I would prefer to use a shell script to iterate over the repositories: If that directory is not a valid git repository, do not run `git gc`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
find /git -name '*.git' -execdir sh -c 'cd {} && git gc' \;
```

This will find every directory matching `*.git` under `/git`, `cd` into it, and run `git gc`.

Comment: Thanks! I got some of the following errors: `sh: line 0: cd: ./.git: Not a directory`, probably because .git can also be a file if it represents a submodule.

Comment: that command complains that its insecure blah blah
`find . -name "*.git" -exec bash -c 'cd {} && git gc' printf {} ';'` works but both of them dont work for directories with spaces in them....  (if `find` returns a folder with spaces on the name its not escaped and causes problems)

Answer (score 1):

On some systems (ie. OSX) the `for` loop treats spaces as delimiters, breaking directory names that contain spaces. Set `IFS` to only use linebreaks `\n` for this to work properly, and reset to default when done:

```
oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; for line in $(find /git -name '*.git'); do (echo $line; cd $line; git gc); done; IFS=$oldIFS
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `find` (version 4.1) from msysgit is too old, `-execdir` option is not supported.

We have to write a for loop instead.

```
for line in $(find /git -name '*.git'); do (cd $line && git gc); done
```